# Get all POST data and send in email

Tags: php, mysql, email

Im trying to use PHP Mail function to send myself an email of all post variables.

So far I have this...

```
$message = foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

mail('liam@site.co.uk', 'sghting', $message);
```

Only the message being submitted is my last post record, can anybody see where im going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    $message .= "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";

mail('liam@site.co.uk', 'sghting', $message);
```

`$message = foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)` is not correct, this will iterate over the results and store the last one. You want to store the values in your $message variable, not echo them.

Comment: Thanks @MitchS, is there a way to put each record on a new line?

Comment: Yes: `"\r\n"`. HTML line breaks (as in your code) would work if the email was HTML (look at the documentation for `mail` on how to send HTML emails). But `"\r\n"` will work if new lines are all you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = "";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
$message .= "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";

mail('liam@site.co.uk', 'sghting', $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally just use `var_export()` for this kind of thing.

```
$message = var_export($_POST,true);
```

If used and set to TRUE, var_export() will return the variable representation instead of outputting it.

Practice example would be:

```
mail('name@site.co.uk', 'Export of the Post Data', var_export($_POST,true));
```

OR if you want to do something more pretty

```
$posted_data = var_export($_POST,true);
$message = '
<h4> Debug Registration Form on XXX </h4>
<p>Here is a dump of the posted data</p>
<pre>
'.$posted_data.'
</pre>
';
mail('name@site.co.uk', 'Export of the Posted Data', $message);
```